# Insert value from price column from database into labels

Tags: sql, vb.net

i want to automatically insert the prices from my database into labels in my application. So for each item it automatically keeps the price up to date, how do i do this? I found this function online:

```
 Public Shared Function GetRecord(sql As String) As String
        Dim result As String
        connection.Open()

        Dim command As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)

        Try
            If command.ExecuteScalar IsNot System.DBNull.Value Then
                result = command.ExecuteScalar
            Else
                result = ""
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex

        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try

        Return result
    End Function
```

then for each label i put:

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT price from product where product_id = 1"
        lblGateu.Text = sql.GetRecord(sql)
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Do you really want to connect to the database and run a query over and over and over to get prices one by one?  Think about loading them into a datatable and getting them as needed.  Otherwise, you will have to explain `it doesn't work` much better.

Comment: This was the only solution i could find to my problem unfortunately, i'm a bit lost when it comes to vb.net... and sorry to be a pain but how would i do that?

Comment: Hi @FreddieMurphy. Do you get an exception or does it run but the label doesn't get updated? Also, what is the output of the query you've typed out if it's run directly on the DB. Also, check the connection string.